# Warning: imagejpeg() [function:imagejpeg]: gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress installation on my root folder,

until yesterday it was working fine, but today it gives following error for i guess generating thumbnail images,

```
Warning: imagejpeg() [function:imagejpeg]: gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: in public_html/wp-includes/media.php on line 459
```

do anyone have any idea regarding this warning??

Please help me

following code is on line 459

```
if ( !imagejpeg( $newimage, $destfilename, apply_filters( 'jpeg_quality', $jpeg_quality, 'image_resize' ) ) )
```

Comment: How are we supported to know what's on line 459?

Comment: Is GD enabled on your site/host?, try adding the following to your .htaccess file:

AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

Comment: till yesterday it was working fine, i do have cpanel access, how do i check that GD is enabled or not?

Comment: just run <?php phpinfo(); ?> file and chech if GD library is enabled or not, if not change settings in php.ini or use ini_set() method..check this link for further info regarding GD http://assets.webassist.com/how-tos/gd_library_ht.pdf

Comment: i have referred you pdf link, and GD is enabled in my server

Comment: No free disk space, or over quota (for WHM/etc) is where we were getting the error from.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**1) Check the space in disk**

Your system must have enough disk space

**2) Check the memory limit**

Set more memory in your php:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","256M");
```

**3) Check the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize**

Set more in your htaccess file:

```
php_value post_max_size 16M
php_value upload_max_filesize 6M
```

**4) put @ in front of the function**

```
@imagejpeg(..............);
```

Point 1) worked for me.

Comment: What does the @ in front of mean?!

Comment: @YeppThat'sMe `@` is to avoid warning messages

Comment: Don't suppress warnings. They are there for a reason. Handle them!

Comment: If its a unrecoverable error and you are in a loop, it will break the loop. You got to handle the error.

Answer (score 35):

You probably tried to create an image from `jpeg` that is not `jpeg`.

I got the same error when I was testing a thumbnail script in **PHP**.
Then I found that the header of my input file was `png` although its extension was `.jpg`.

So, I edited my script so that if there is an error in creating an image from `jpeg`, it tries to create it from `png` *(or `gif` if another error occurs)*.

Comment: This is the real answer

Comment: Better to use `exif_imagetype` function instead of brute forcing

Answer (score 6):

You have to use a function to correctly determine mime type of image. A png image that have jpg extension will lead to this error.

To avoid this error, you have to get [correct mime type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) of image.

```
function getImage($path) {
switch(mime_content_type($path)) {
  case 'image/png':
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($path);
    break;
  case 'image/gif':
    $img = imagecreatefromgif($path);
    break;
  case 'image/jpeg':
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
    break;
  case 'image/bmp':
    $img = imagecreatefrombmp($path);
    break;
  default:
    $img = null; 
  }
  return $img;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

On PHP7 `imagecreatefromjpeg` started throwing fatal errors when you try to open an invalid file, which even the `@` sign cannot catch.

Use the following instead:

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filename));
if ($im !== false) { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a Same error .But now i am solved the same issue.

Answer is :We  are uploading png and it converts to  jpg . 
    Please check with jpg it works.And we need to convert png to jpg so other functions are available please check on same.

Below code will be useful to convert images using GD Library.

```
//variable declare or parameter use
$originalImage ="1.jpg";
$quality=100; // for jpg good quality
$outputImage;   //for source file save.  


// jpg, png, gif or bmp?
    $exploded = explode('.',$originalImage);
    $ext = $exploded[count($exploded) - 1]; 

    if (preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/i',$ext))
        $imageTmp=imagecreatefromjpeg($originalImage);
    else if (preg_match('/png/i',$ext))
        $imageTmp=imagecreatefrompng($originalImage);
    else if (preg_match('/gif/i',$ext))
        $imageTmp=imagecreatefromgif($originalImage);
    else if (preg_match('/bmp/i',$ext))
        $imageTmp=imagecreatefrombmp($originalImage);
    else
        return 0;

    // quality is a value from 0 (worst) to 100 (best)
    imagejpeg($imageTmp, $outputImage, $quality);
    imagedestroy($imageTmp);
```

Comment: Nice work @shashik493 ..It helps me great..thank you so much