# Getting Error Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error

Tags: php, wordpress, gd

I am import the feeds data in our database by using API. But when i import the data getting error "Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: in /home/veebliss/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor.php on line 337".

Here is the code that are in line number 337

```
$result = call_user_func_array( $function, $arguments );
```

I have already check the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611883/warning-imagejpeg-functionimagejpeg-gd-jpeg-jpeg-library-reports-unrecov/) & also fixed the upload_max_filesize, max_execution_time, max_file_uploads, post_max_size but still i am getting same error.

do anyone have any idea regarding this warning & error ?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help !

Answer (score 0):

I think your hard disk space is full.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
"imagecreatefromjpeg JPEG library reports unrecoverable error"
It took me some time to sort out the cause in my code.
I'm using a custom handler to print php errors : set_error_handler().

When I put in comment this handler the imagecreatefromjpeg() error stop from happening.
I dont understand the cause. This must be an intenal PHP problem...

For PNG file, using imagecreatefrompng(), there where no error.

So sommething to do whith set_error_handler().
Hope it helps.

PS. I'm working on a old machine : Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) PHP/5.6.3

voila / my english is not to bad ...