# Get image width and height of image in blob

Tags: php, mysql

I have some images in a MySQL Database, each stored in BLOB fields.
How can I evaluate the width and height of the images in pixels?

Comment: Use [imagecreatefromstring()](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) to turn the blob data into an image, then use [getimagesize()](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to retrieve its dimensions.

Comment: may be while storing the image in DB , you can get the size and store it in DB also .That will reduce the trouble . Simple

Comment: @CodingAnt unfortunately this is not an option, as there already are hundreds of images in the database.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage thanks for the advice. I'm gonna try this.

Comment: i am curious why you have opted to store images in a database. Why not store the file locally ? It's not only faster, but more easier to manage ...

Comment: @KarelG You're right. I share your opinion. I'm working for a client on a very very old code and I've been asked to only make minor changes to the code.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have retrieved the image from the blob field in the database via a mysqli_query and assigned it variable **$image**.  You can use this code:

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($image);
$width = imagesx($im);
$height = imagesy($im);
```

Comment: Hm. Unfortunately this doesn't work for me right now as I get this error, I can't interpret:

-----------------------

imagecreatefromstring(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: 
in line 38 of file ImgDoc.inc.php

| Only content in this line is:  $img = imagecreatefromstring($imageArray[$key]["Image"]);

Comment: You may need to set the memory limit higher.  Here is another page that may help fix this error:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611883/warning-imagejpeg-functionimagejpeg-gd-jpeg-jpeg-library-reports-unrecov