# Cannot optimize image in PHP

Tags: php

This is the code I have:

```
$from = ...; // original uploaded file
$target = ...; // save path for optimized file
@unlink($target); // removes file if already exists
$image_o = imagecreatefromjpeg($from); // get a file
imagejpeg($image_o, $target, 85); // save optimized
imagedestroy($image_o); // free memory
```

But it doesn't do anything. This is going in loop, but now I test it on the single file. Seems to be working on smaller files. I tried image with size ~120 kB and optimized OK. But file with more than 1 MB, it will do nothing and those are files I really need to optimize. I also tried this:

```
set_time_limit(6000);
ini_set('memory_limit', '200M');
```

But no help. I'm working on a shared hosting, so I have no access to the `php.ini` or to install 3rd party PHP extension. Is there an alternative for `imagecreatefromjpeg` which seems to be the problem?

Comment: How many images ? If you treat 1 big image does it work ?

Comment: There is like 5-6 small images and 1-3 big. But it doesn't even work with single one (the big one).

Comment: have you tried `ini_set('display_errors',1) ; error_reporting(E_ALL) ;` ? Maybe there is a warning... jpeg not being a jpeg or something else

Comment: `Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error` what does it mean?

Comment: Well... that just mean there is an error, thats a good point ;) take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21045415/2846837 : probably... a jpeg not being a jpeg ;)

Comment: Oh thanks, I will look at it and try some recommendations.

Comment: I solved the problem - uploaded image has mime type of PNG, but its extension is JPG... I think my clients will kill me one day :)