# imagecreatefromjpeg got gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: Bogus Huffman table definition

Tags: php, gd, prestashop-1.6, php-gd

I have migrated from a shared hosting with apache and Prestashop, to a debian 9 VPS server, i got problems with images like those
[image]

So in Prestashop image back end page, i tried to regenerate the shop images so i got this error:

```
imagecreatefromjpeg got gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: Bogus Huffman table definition
```

I tried this solutions [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10668155/926171) but the problem persist.

Thanks