# How to check image open without error using url in php?

Tags: php, image

I need to check image open without error using url , When am open the image it got the message like cannot be displayed image because it contains errors.

So I got error like imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error when resize image that's why am plan to check image open without error or not before resize image.

Am tried like below code,

```
$url = "path/to/sample.jpg"

if(file_exits($url)) {
    echo "image exits" 
} else {
    echo "image not exists"
}
```

But this not working always came else part only. and also am tried like,

```
getimagesize($url)
```

but this also not worked got size in that image but it have some errors in image.

Please give me solution for my problem.

Comment: `@getimagesize($url)` used this for temporary solution

Comment: i have faced the same problem. if you use `getimagesize()` it will consume more memory on server. that's why i have used `file_exits($url)`.

Comment: Might be worth giving this a read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611883/warning-imagejpeg-functionimagejpeg-gd-jpeg-jpeg-library-reports-unrecov

Comment: what output are you getting by using `print_r(@getimagesize($external_link))`?

Comment: Got getimage result like Array ( [0] => 37 [1] => 55 [2] => 2 [3] => width="37" height="55" [bits] => 8 [channels] => 3 [mime] => image/jpeg )