# why imagecreatefromjpeg() function is not opening the file from the folder

Tags: php

I want to resize the image file after upload with the help of imagecreatefromjpeg function but this function is unable to access the file from the folder as it's throwing the error i.e., **

> imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable
>   error: in D:\xampp\htdocs\resize\index.php

** but file is uploaded & I wrote the following code.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="f1">
    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Upload">
</form>

<?php
ini_set("memory_limit","256M");
if(isset($_POST['btn'])) 
{

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['f1']['tmp_name'], "images/".$_FILES['f1']['name'])) 
    {          


        $filename = "images/".$_FILES['f1']['name'];


        $original_info = getimagesize($filename);
         $original_w = $original_info[0];
        $original_h = $original_info[1];
        echo "<img src =$filename>";
        if( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {
          // it's enabled, so do something        

            $original_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);         
            $thumb_w = 100;
            $thumb_h = 60;
            $thumb_img = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_w, $thumb_h);
            $thumb_filename = "new.jpg";
            imagecopyresampled($thumb_img, $original_img,
                               0, 0,
                               0, 0,
                               $thumb_w, $thumb_h,
                               $original_w, $original_h);
            imagejpeg($thumb_img, $thumb_filename);
            imagedestroy($thumb_img);
            imagedestroy($original_img); 
        }       
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: imagejpeg() \[function:imagejpeg\]: gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611883/warning-imagejpeg-functionimagejpeg-gd-jpeg-jpeg-library-reports-unrecov)

Comment: I'm sure someone else will answer your specific question but I've found (doing the same thing) that most servers nowadays include the ImageMagick library which makes it a whole lot easier. It's worth a look.

Comment: I hve seen that, but not useful for me

Comment: are you sure you are uploading a `jpeg` image? as the function name says `imagecreatefromjpeg` it only accepts jpeg I guess.

Comment: yes................

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure of the type of file.

```
<?php
    $type = exif_imagetype($filename);
    // types 1=>gif, 2=>jpg, 3=>png, 6=>bmp
    switch ($type) {
        case 1 : $img = imageCreateFromGif ( $src );break;
        case 2 : $img = imageCreateFromJpeg( $src );break;
        case 3 : $img = imageCreateFromPng ( $src );break;
        case 6 : $img = imageCreateFromBmp ( $src );break;
    }
    // or if you cannot use exif_imagetype
    // you can use getImageSize
    $type = getImageSize($filename);
    switch ($type) {
        case 'image/gif'  : $img = imageCreateFromGif ( $filename ); break;
        case 'image/jpeg' : $img = imageCreateFromJpeg( $filename ); break;
        case 'image/png'  : $img = imageCreateFromPng ( $filename ); break;
        case 'image/bmp'  : $img = imageCreateFromBmp ( $filename ); break;
    }
//// than you can create new file with resize or crop...
```

?>